# Wrong/right counter for user input evaluation PHP

Tags: php, validation, session, input, counter

I have built a simple calculator that uses random numbers and operations (+,-,*,/). Users can fill in a form for each question and their input is evaluated. However, instead of just displaying "That's right" or "That's wrong" for single questions, I want to show the accuracy/failure of their input over more questions (e.g. 50). Therefore, I am looking for a numerical counter, one that might just consist in a simple number that counts up everytime the user gives the correct answer (might be green), and a second one (red) that counts when the user gives a wrong answer. Both numbers should be displayed constantly. After 50 times, it would display the percentage of right answers.

Can I do this with sessions? And if so, how? Right now, the page is refreshing with every new click on the submit button. The more specific you can get the better since I am not an expert (yet). THANKS for any help!! Please finde my code below:

```
<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: x-large">


    <?php
    $number1 = rand(1,100);
    $number2 = rand(1,100);
    $number3 = rand(1,20);
    $number4 = rand(1,20);

    switch(rand(0,3)) {
        case 0:
            $solution = $number1 + $number2;
            echo "$number1+$number2=?";
            break;
        case 1:
            $solution = $number1 - $number2;
            echo "$number1-$number2=?";
            break;
        case 2:
            $solution = $number3 * $number4;
            echo "$number3*$number4=?";
            break;
        case 3:
            $solution = $number3 / $number4;
            echo "$number3/$number4=?";
            break;
    }
    ?>


<form action="form10.php" method="post">
Your Answer:<br>
<input type="integer" name="answer">
<input type="hidden" name="solution" value="<?php echo $solution; ?>">
<input type="Submit" value="Submit!">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['answer']) && isset($_POST['solution'])) {
    if ($_POST["answer"] == round($_POST['solution'],1)) {
        echo "<font color='#008000'> That's right! </font>";;
    } else {
      echo "That's wrong!";
    }
}
?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need a $counter value to persist...

```
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>">
```

and then to increment...

```
if( isset($_POST['counter']) )
   $counter= $_POST['counter'] + 1;
```

Example 'test.php' = keep clicking the Submit button...

```
<?php

$counter=0;
if( isset($_POST['counter']) )
   $counter= $_POST['counter'] + 1;

?>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
Your Answer:<br>
<input type="integer" name="answer">
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>">
<input type="Submit" value="Submit!">
<br>
Counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But then the counter still doesn't count up since the page is reloaded every time the user clicks "submit". The counter stays one.

Comment: Also, I am having problems counting in two counters this way: One counter that goes up for every right answer and another one that goes up for every wrong answer. Really appreciate your support!

Comment: Your PHP to process the POST parameters will have to be *before* the javascript which references the $counter variable.

Comment: added example of incrementing counter

Comment: Hey, Tony! Thanks, makes total sense. Just one last thing: This way, it will increase the counter every time a user submits the form. However, I would love to implement an IF condition. It should increase Counter 1 if the user enters the right answer, and Counter 2 if the user enters any wrong answer. That is what I am struggling with, how to increase the counter depending on the input validation - which happens AFTER the html form at the moment (s. code above). Sorry for asking again and tons of thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I had an urgent appointment with a couple of pints of 'Speckled Hen' at the local pub :)  - you said ... AFTER ..., but just think what happens: php/form is submitted, all of it runs - only 1st time your "if(isset($_POST['answer'])" is false. 2nd time the whole thing runs again. It does not matter if the 'php tests' are 'after' the javascript. if your PHP is put before the javascript, it is executed after the form has been submitted the first time... see what I mean?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! It worked! Please enjoy a pint for me as well :)